# Websockets VS SSE

Tags: php, websockets

Suppose I have a service which requires to *seek* the database for different data once and in a while.
For this I have 2 or 3 SSE, each one with a different *retry* basetime (20000 miliseconds, 1000 miliseconds...).
**What I'd like to know is if websockets can handle different "data type" accordingly to the request**, for example, could I create **one** websocket to handle a notification system, a chat system, a group system instead of separated ***SSEs*** and treat data differently with javascript? And if so, would it be of higher interest (performance) than actually performing different queries to the server through different *SSEs*?

If this is possible then would it be bad design to create multiple sockets for each service here?

Comment: What is an SSE?  Anyway, you can send whatever you want to over a websocket.  You can send a packet with a header that specifies the data type, and then deserialize the remaining data from the packet into the appropriate object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's [Streaming SIMD Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Server Sent Events

Comment: @RobertHarvey would I be able to "create one websocket to handle a notification system, a chat system, a group system" in only ONE websocket?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?  A websocket is just a communications channel, is it not?  You would only need separate websockets if you were communicating with separate servers.

Comment: **[cross-posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'")** at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896917/regarding-sse-vs-websockets

Comment: @JimmyHoffa unless completely drunk or the greatest hacker in the world, I believe SIMD extensions and PHP get along as cats and elephants hang out together

Comment: I think you're missing the more fundamental distinguishing factor which is communication channels.  Whereas SSE is one way from the server to the client, WebSocket is 2 way.  Websocket coding will also force you to ensure you maintain the connection whereas SSE will depend more on the browser.  If you only require data from server to client, I would recommend SSE as the implementation is much simpler.